# PowerShell file editing problem in tkinter

Tags: python, powershell, file, tkinter, io

Ok, so i created a program in tkinter that will edit FNaF saves, but i ran into a problem with PowerShell file text replacing. May som1 help me? Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from os import system

root = Tk()
root.title("Fife Nights at Freddy's Unlocker 1.0")



header = Label(root, text="FNaF Unlocker 1.0", font=("Consolas 40 bold")).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
f1l = Label(root, text="Już wkrótce!")
f1l.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')
f2l = Label(root, text="FNaF 2")
f2l.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='w')
f3l = Label(root, text="Już wkrótce!")
f3l.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='w')
f4l = Label(root, text="Już wkrótce!")
f4l.grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='w')
f5l = Label(root, text="Już wkrótce!")
f5l.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='w')
f6l = Label(root, text="FNaF 6 (Freddy Fazbear's Pizzeria Simulator)")
f6l.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='w')
f7l = Label(root, text="FNaF 7 (Ultimate Custom Night)")
f7l.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky='w')

def fnaf(number):
    f2npre = IntVar()
    f2naft = IntVar()
    f2ep = Entry(root, textvariable=f2npre)
    f2ep.grid(column=3, row=2)
    text2 = "Wpisz, którą noc masz odblokowaną (pod przyciskiem \"Continue\" w grze)"
    f2ep.insert(0, text2)
    f2ep2 = Entry(root, textvariable=f2naft)
    f2ep2.grid(column=4, row=2)
    text22 = "Wpisz numer nocy, którą chcesz odblokować"
    f2ep2.insert(0, text22)
    if number == 2:
        def submit2():
            system(f"powershell -c \'Get-Content $env:APPDATA\\MMFApplications\\freddy2 | % \u007B $_ -replace \'level={f2npre.get()}\',\'level={f2naft.get()}\'\u007D | Set-Content $env:APPDATA\MMFApplications\\freddy2\'")

        f2sb = Button(root, text="Akceptuj", command=submit2).grid(column=5, row=2)

f2b = Button(root, text="Edytuj", command=fnaf(2))
f2b.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky='w')
f6b = Button(root, text="Edytuj")
f6b.grid(column=1, row=6, sticky='w')
f7b = Button(root, text="Edytuj")
f7b.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky='w')

mainloop()
```

Here is also full save file:

```
[freddy2]
cine=1
level=6
beatgame=1
beat6=1
```

I tried changing file location from `%appdata%\...` to `$env:APPDATA\...` but still doesn't work.

Comment: i don't know what tkinter is and don't understand your code, but the PowerShell part needs to escape reserved characters  []().\^$|?*+{}   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2#escaping-characters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to provide details of the ***specific*** errors/problems you're having. "This code doesn't work" is not enough information to solve the problem. See [ask] and the [help] for more information on asking good questions. See the [tour] for an intro to how things are run here.